# Existence of a function that has a non-measurable $\lim \inf$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that there exists a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \{0,1\}$ such that

(a) $\int f(x,t)dx=1 \hspace{0.4cm} \forall t\neq0 $

(b) $\lim\inf_{t\to 0} f(x,t)$ is not measurable.

I tried to construct a non-measurable set so i could use it but i failed,should i construct such a function or just focus on the existence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to give an explicit construction of a non measurable set, so we presume the existence of such a set.

Let $A$ be a non measurable subset of $(0,1]$.

Let $\phi_n: ({1 \over n+1}, {1 \over n}] \to (0,1]$ be the segment of the graph defined by interpolation
between the points $({1 \over n+1}, 0)$ and $({1\over n}, 1)$. Define $\phi(t) = \phi_n(t)$ for $t \in ({1 \over n+1}, {1 \over n}]$.

Note that as $t$ ranges through $(0,1]$, $\phi(t)$ takes all values in $(0,1]$
infinitely often.

Define
$f(x,t) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \notin (0,1] \text{ or } t \notin (0,1]\\
0, & x=\phi(t) \text{ and } x \in A^c \\
1, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Note that for a fixed $t$, the function $x \mapsto f(x,t)$ is $1_{(0,1]}$ except
at possible one value, hence it is measurable, and $\int f(x,t)dx = 1$.

Note that $\liminf_{t \to 0} f(x,t) = 1_A(x)$, which is not measurable.